# concatenating python strings in a loop

Tags: python, string, generator

I am using enums and string.join() method to form a help string in Python:

I have the following code segment:

```
from enum import Enum

class Estimators(Enum):
    rsac = 1
    msac = 2
```

Now, I create a help string as follows:

```
est_help = 'Valid options are: [' + (str(i.name) + ', ' for i in Estimators) + ']'
```

This throws a TypeError exception as:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'generator' objects
```

I was wondering what I am doing wrong. The `i.name` is of string type.

Comment: `(str(i.name) + ', ' for i in RobustEstimators)` is a generator, so you can't add it to a string, exactly as the error message tells you. Did you mean `', '.join(...)`?

Comment: Maybe you need `est_help = 'Valid options are: [' + str(i.name) + ', ' for i in RobustEstimators + ']'`?

Comment: @KevinGuan how do you imagine that would help?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Oops, I didn't see the `+ ']'`, I thought that it's a list comprehension.  Sorry for this :P

Comment: Ah yes, I see. I should have used the join method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message tells you what you are doing wrong - attempting to concatenate a string and a generator. What you want to do is to make a list using list comprehension based on the generator, then use that

```
est_help = 'Valid options are: [{}]'.format( ', '.join( i.name for i in Estimators))
```

Let's decompose this into individual steps:

1. Create the list `[rsac,msac]`: `est_list = [str(i.name) for i in Estimators]`
2. Create a string with the list elements separated by a comma `'rsac, msac'`: `est_str = ', '.join( est_list )`
3. Insert the string into your text template: `est_help = 'Valid options are: [{}]'.format( est_str )`, and get the resulting string `Valid options are: [rsac, msac]'`

**edit: modified code incorporating suggestions from comments**

```
est_help = 'Valid options are: [{}]'.format( ', '.join( i.name for i in Estimators ) )
```

Comment: You can save some line noise by using a generator expression instead of a list comprehension - just drop the `[]` inside the call to `join`. Also, carried over from the OP but still worth mentioning, `i.name` is already a string, so you can drop the `str` call for `', '.join(i.name for i in Estimators)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can join Estimators' members:

```
'Valid options are: [%s]' % ', '.join(Estimators.__members__)
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution

```
est_help = 'Valid options are: [' + ",".join(str(i) for i in Estimators) + ']'
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain for the OP (and future visitors) how/why this code works, or how to get to it from the position in the question, rather than just saying "here's the code".

Answer (score 0):

Since none of the posts mentioned yet work for me(I always get 'type' object is not iterable, @lvc figured it out, I had the enum from PyPI which doesn't have the iterator function built in) here is my solution to the problem

```
from enum import Enum

class Estimators(Enum):
    rsac = 1
    msac = 2

e = Estimators
attributes = [attr for attr in vars(e) if not attr.startswith('__')]

est_help = 'Valid options are: ' + str(attributes).replace('\'','')

print est_help
```

I get the members of the class using vars since they are stored in dictionary format and then filter out all the members that start with `__` and then since the elements of the list show up as strings with `'` I replace those with an empty string.

Some of the code can be reduced if I combine my solution with @SigveKolbeinson's answer like so

```
est_help = 'Valid options are: [{}]'.format( ', '.join( [str(i) for i in vars(Estimators) if not i.startswith('__')]))
```

Comment: The difference is probably that you are using the `enum` package off PyPI. You can get the backported stdlib version with the `enum34` package, and the versions iterating `Estimators` directly do work in it.

Comment: @lvc that was it. Thanks, I didn't know about that.